# Calculation of average of all possible slices of 1d-array

Tags: numpy, slice, average

I have a (big) 1d array of measurement data. I want to calculate the average for every possible slice defined by a start-index and a stop-index. Like cutting at both ends of my data and average every possible cut.
The result should be stored in a square 2D array (actually a triangle, as the start index must be smaller than the stop index).

Using loops works, but takes a long time.

Is there a way to speed this up?

I have this code:

```
N = 5
data = np.arange(N)  # example
av = np.zeros((N, N))
for i in range(av.shape[0]):
    for j in range(av.shape[1]):
        av[j, i] = np.mean(data[i:j+1])
```

This works, but takes a long time. For a similar calculation (differences of elements instead of averages of slices), I found this very fast solution:

```
dist = np.subtract.outer(data, data)
```

But I did not figure out how this could be done with averages of slices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option with a summation, then division by the number of items:

```
a = np.arange(len(data))

av = (np.tril(np.repeat(data[:,None], len(data), axis=1)).cumsum(axis=0)
     /np.tril((a[:,None]-a+1))
     )
```

Output:

```
array([[0. , nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [0.5, 1. , nan, nan, nan],
       [1. , 1.5, 2. , nan, nan],
       [1.5, 2. , 2.5, 3. , nan],
       [2. , 2.5, 3. , 3.5, 4. ]])
```

Intermediates:

```
# repeat data to square shape and keep lower triangle
np.tril(np.repeat(data[:,None], len(data), axis=1))
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 0],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]])

# get the cumulated sum
[…].cumsum()
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 3,  3,  2,  0,  0],
       [ 6,  6,  5,  3,  0],
       [10, 10,  9,  7,  4]])

# compute the divider
a = np.arange(len(data))
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

np.tril((a[:,None]-a+1))
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 2, 1, 0, 0],
       [4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
       [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]])
```

##### performance

One a 1000 integer input (`data = np.arange(1000)`)

```
# nested for loop
6.28 s ± 142 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# vectorized numpy
12.3 ms ± 427 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: I'm impressed ... thank you for the lesson.